# android - interstitial ad showing on click

Tags: java, android

In my new game I want to show interstitial ads. With a button click the game restarts and I want the ads to show up only every 15th time. The problem is that it is shown every time the game starts. Where is the fault?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 
    InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    public int playcount = 0;
 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);

        // set the ad unit ID
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitial_full_screen));

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .build();

        // Load ads into Interstitial Ads
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
        TextView playctv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        SharedPreferences prefsplay = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        playcount = prefsplay.getInt("play_number", 0);
        playctv.setText(String.valueOf(playcount));
    }

    public void restart(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GameScreen.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        playcount++;

        SharedPreferences prefsplay = this
            .getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey",
                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        prefsplay.edit().putInt("play_number", playcount)
            .apply();
    }

    private void showInterstitial() {
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded())
            mInterstitialAd.show();
    }

    private void adView() {
        mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.interstitial_full_screen));
        final AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

    public void gameover() { 
        if (playcount == 10) {
            playcount = 0;
            mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                public void onAdLoaded() {
                    mInterstitialAd.show();    //We are executing this code only if ad is loaded, no need to check it again

                    SharedPreferences prefsplay = getApplicationContext()
                        .getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey",
                                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    prefsplay.edit().putInt("play_number", playcount)
                        .apply();

                    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                        .build();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Activity_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/rect" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    android:scaleType="center" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageview1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageview1"
    android:alpha="0.7"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Score"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:alpha="0.9"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="sco"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="0:500"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:alpha="0.7"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
    android:text="Highscore"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView4"
    android:text="Hs"
    android:textSize="25sp" />



    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"               ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_home_footer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
        android:onClick="restart"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_revert"

        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="xxx"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.1" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logoone"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".GameScreen"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />

    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />


</manifest>
```

Comment: Really? How can you take influence in how much it is showing up then?

Comment: [https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362?hl=en] read here more about what you shouldn't do, it is possible pragrammatacally but they will bann you later

Comment: Okay I see. Is it allowed to start an ad right after the player is game over then?

Comment: How do you mean if it excepts restart()?

Comment: you shouldn't show an add every specific time

Comment: So it should show up randomly?

Comment: yes you can't implement code to show them as you want

Comment: So it's just depending on time then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132602/discussion-between-khalil-m-and-joe-s).

Comment: @KhalilM Would you help me with my new problem?

Comment: Never put all your code in a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code needs a lot of fixing. I'm putting one by one here.

- The `restart` function should use `startActivityForResult`

  ```
  private final int ACTION_GAME = 100; 

  public void restart(View view) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, GameScreen.class);
      startActivityForResult(intent, ACTION_GAME);
      playcount++;

      SharedPreferences prefsplay = this
          .getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      prefsplay.edit().putInt("play_number", playcount).apply();
  }
  ```
- As you've started the `GameScreen` activity for a result, you need to override the `onActivityResult`

  ```
  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      switch (requestCode) {
          case ACTION_GAME:
              gameover();
              break;
          default:
              break;
      }
  }
  ```
- Now in the `gameover` function you need to check the saved value in your preference for the `playcount`.

  ```
  public void gameover() { 
      // Get the saved value
      SharedPreferences prefsplay = this
          .getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      playcount = prefsplay.getInt("play_number", 0);

      if (playcount >= 10) {
          playcount = 0;
          showInterstitial();

          SharedPreferences prefsplay = getApplicationContext()
              .getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
          prefsplay.edit().putInt("play_number", playcount).apply();

          // Start loading the new ad
          loadNewAd();
      }
  }
  ```
- I've introduced `loadNewAd()` function which might look like this

  ```
  private void loadNewAd() {
      final AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
      mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
  }
  ```
- And the `onCreate` function needs to be modified like this

  ```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
      mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);

      // set the ad unit ID
      mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitial_full_screen));

      // Call adView here
      adView();

      TextView playctv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

      SharedPreferences prefsplay = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey",
          Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      playcount = prefsplay.getInt("play_number", 0);
      playctv.setText(String.valueOf(playcount));
  }
  ```
- Finally, as you're using `startActivityForResult` you need to set the result while finishing your `GameScreen` activity. So when you finish or return from the `GameScreen` activity, you need to do this.

  ```
  GameScreen.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
  GameScreen.finish();
  ```

Comment: I get an error in my `gameover()` method, because the SharedPreferences cant use `prefsplay` two times in the same scope, how to fix that?

Comment: Declare the `SharedPreference` as public and use it every other places in your `MainActivity`.

Comment: Of course, I will! But to understand what you mean - the last part is only needed when I'm finishing or returning my GameScreen? So as long as I'm in the GameScreen itself I don't need it?

Comment: As long as you are in your `GameScreen` you don't need to show the ad right?? So if you want to show an ad after playing 15 times, you need to handle the event from the `MainActivity`.